# Setting up cpanel server for PHP UTF-8 characters [BOM error]

Tags: php, apache, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I've been having a bit of a headache getting my server working with UTF-8 characters. I have a list of UK towns some of which have Gaelic characters and some Scottish ones also have special characters it seems.

To facilitate this the developer put a BOM at the start of the PHP file. On his server a Ubuntu setup this worked fine as apparently his PHP defaults to UTF-8. However on my server it caused an issue with the headers having been already sent (Obviously reading the BOM as ABC instead of a BOM declaration).

I went into WHM and set the Default_charset in php.ini to UTF-8, and php info reads the default charset as UTF-8. I didn't want to edit the httpd.conf to set Apache to UTF-8 across the entire server as this would possible cause problems elsewhere so I set UTF-8 in the .htaccess file as follows

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

However the BOM was still being read as text and messing up the headers. With the BOM removed the page and the site works fine, just the special characters are read as random ISO characters.

I don;t have much experience with server settings or administration and none with BOM or setting up and running PHP in UTF-8 so any help or leads would be a great help. no doubt I've done something extremely stupid and obvious.

Comment: What you did is enough: Removing BOM and setting the encoding in file to UTF-8 WITHOUT BOM (use NOTEPAD++ or SublimeText) is enough to make it work as UTF-8.

For me, you should remove BOM everywhere. It causes so many troubles all the time. For example if you make your htaccess use BOM, you'll see that your server will go through a SERVER ERROR 500. And by the way, did you force the CHARSET in html pages to UTF-8 ??

Comment: Yeah my documents have always been setup as UTF-8 without BOM with notepad++ (without me even knowing, but as this was a build from another developer I had to copy paste everything but the BOM into a new document). Also yes the HTML has the meta data in the header saying it's UTF-8

Comment: City names are from a database or is just a plain text ?

Comment: They're entered as text in the PHP file, some are UTF-8 character some are html character codes.